# handler.postDelayed cannot update boolean variable

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make a code that wait until a result presents (provided by a service) or a second has passed.

My code can detect a change in result variable but cannot detect a change made to "waiting" variable. I update waiting variable in a runnable, executed with Handler.postDelayed(). I've tried using @Volatile, but still no luck.

```
var waiting = true
var r = Runnable {
    waiting=false
    Log.d("Timeout", "timeout")
}

val handler = Handler()
handler.postDelayed(r,1000)
while(returnCall==null && waiting){continue;}
// handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
```

I expected an object from a service or skip the process after waiting for a second. The code never goes beyond the while statement. "timeout" is never printed to Logcat.

If returnCall has been assigned, the code does proceed AND the Runnable is executed as expected (prints timeout to Logcat).

EDIT:
I use this code inside a callback function

```
var jsInterfaceCallback = object : MyJsInterface.myJsInterfaceCallback(){
    override fun onCommand (command : String, data : HashMap<String, Any>) : MutableMap<String, Any>{
        returnCall = null
        // Pass intent to service

        var waiting = true
        var r = Runnable {
            waiting=false
            Log.d("Timeout", "timeout")
        }

        val handler = Handler()
        handler.postDelayed(r,1000)
        while(returnCall==null && waiting){continue;}
        // handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
        if(returnCall != null){
            return returnCall!!
        }
        return mutableMapOf()
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need a spin lock? Consider callback function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a spin lock to block the thread, the `Runnable` posted on the same thread has no chances to execute (the thread is always busy doing the `while` loop)

Instead of using `while` loop to detect variable change, you should write a callback function to do the follow up action and call it when timeout or your service produced the result.

```
fun callback(result : YourResultType?)
{
   if(result != null)
   {
       //handle the result produced by the service
   }
   else
   {
       //timeout, do what ever you want to follow up
   }
}

var r = Runnable {
    Log.d("Timeout", "timeout")
    callback(null)
}

val handler = Handler()
handler.postDelayed(r,1000)
```

Comment: my code is actually inside a callback function which return the result to another object. can I impement your solution? I am confused on how I should pass the result to the caller. Please see my edit on the question.

Comment: As you want to return the result directly in your function, it must involve blocking the thread. If it is running on the UI thread, you shouldn't do so. Yet, if it is NOT running on the UI thread you can take a look at [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long))

Comment: thank you for your answer. I figured out that I can make the Runnable runs on another thread after I read your answer. For now, I am using Timer.schedule(). I don't know if this is efficient for this case.

Comment: The callback is called from a javascript interface attached to a webview, so I guess it's not on the UI thread.